# Using Dijkstra's Algorithm for pathfinding on a grid

Tags: c++, algorithm, dijkstra, path-finding

Once again having a problem with path finding this time The Dijkstra's

I have read Dijkstra's and its application on a various number of sites.
It's mostly explained for a Graph and finding out the shortest path to all nodes from a source node.

What I am unable to figure out is how to use Dijkstra's for path finding on a grid as explained on [Wikipedia picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Dijkstras_progress_animation.gif).

since on a grid we have a single destination and we have to figure out the shortest distance to it from the source. I am unable to relate it to the Dijkstra's on a graph.
There are no tiles to be marked as INFINITY or to compare the distance with other path's/Nodes.

The question in short is how do we proceed using Dijkstra's to find a path in grid using the actual graph algorithm for which this algorithm is defined.
Do we proceed like BFS and call it Dijkstra's for a grid or is there a difference? because I am unable to figure out any :/

Thank you :)

Comment: `as explained on Wikipedia picture`  What Wikipedia picture?

Comment: Each grid cell has a connection of constant length of 1 to all of its direct neighbours.

Comment: It looks like your problem is that you don't understand Dijkstra's algorithm for a graph either. A grid can be easily converted to a graph. I don't know how you have it set up, but each tile could be a node and they are connected by an edge of length 1.

Comment: Dijkstra on a graph with edges of weight 1 (like your grid) can be replaced by BFS. But you can easily adapt Dijkstra's algorithm by treating cell `(i,j)` as e.g graph's node numbered `i*height+j`

Comment: If you want to be fancy, sqrt(2) for diagonal moves makes it a bit harder.

Comment: On a grid you probably should be using A*.  BFS, A* and Dijkstra's algorithm are all closely related, differing only based on certain simplifying assumptions.

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial about A*: http://www.policyalmanac.org/games/aStarTutorial.htm  It helped me a lot. Dijsktra is exactly the same but without adding H (the heuristic)

Comment: thank you for your answers.

Yes I have already implemented A* on a grid and I know how it works.
But I want to learn and implement Dijkstra's as it's described on Wikipedia's pseudocode. There it doesn't seem to have any link with A*

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sorry I didn't provide the link to the picture.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to apply dijkstra's algorithm in a grid there is no need for any modifications, since a grid is  a graph in which a node (cell) has 4/8 children (depending on your connectivity) which are the neighbors. Therefore, all you have to do is: choose your root node (where to start), assign it value 0 and then evaluate the 4/8 neighbors, using as cost just 1 (or sqrt(2) if for the 4 diagonal neighbors if you are using 8-connectivity). This root node has to be labeled as visited and the neighbors evaluated are labeled as open. Then, you pick the node(cell) in evaluated that has a minimum value (in this case, all of them will have value 1) so you choose any of them. When adding the neighbors to the open list, it will happen that some of these neigbors are already visited, so you just ignore them. If the are already in the open list, you recompute their value and if they are unvisited, you compute their value and add them to open, and mark the current node as closed.

In fact, you will see that there is no difference at all with the generic Dijkstra's algorithm you have been reading for graphs.

NOTE: in order to be efficient when getting the minimum of the open list, it is recommended to use a heap (usually a binary heap) instead of running the min function along all the open nodes at every iteration.

Comment: Well thank's a lot.
This definitely helped.As explained it's almost exactly like A*.
just one more question.If I follow the original algorithm Do i need to mark every node's distance/cost as infinity from source and then check with each neighboring node if it's less and change the values?
or do I just remove heuristics and G-score function from my A* as you explained above(If i understood correctly) ?

Comment: Yes, you need an initialization value which usually is infinity (it can be any negative number for instance as well).

Comment: Isn't that gonna increase the time complexity.
I mean marking all the elements in using loop [i][j] as infinity.
Or is there another way?

Comment: Well, you have to do it. I mean, when you are building your grid you initialize its values somehow (assume you do it offline). Also, this grid will have n cells and the Dijsktra's algorithm with a heap is O(nlog n) and the grid initialization is O(n) so it increases its complexity but not too much (you will be surprised how fast are computers nowadays iterating over a vector because of the prefetching, etc).

Comment: That is very true but I was concerned from the view point of competitive programming.

Comment: If you do it in your class constructor that would take you very little time. You could just ignore initial value and use the unvisited label since unvisited means value = inf, but anyway you have to initialize this label.